# What to use for "localhost" that includes PHP/SQL functionality?

Tags: web-hosting, php, wordpress, localhost, sql-server

I really do not want to install Linux at the moment, I would have to borrow a USB key, move files, format it, flash it, format it again, move files back, give it back...

What would you recommend that is lightweight, ***easily and cleanly uninstallable*** afterwards (will install Linux when I get a new DVD-ROM, which will be in ~2 weeks), that also supports PHP and SQL? To be precise, I want to install a Wordpress blog, a few plugins, etc, and develop a theme.

If there is no such thing for Windows (7, x64 if that matters), let me know too, I will borrow the USB key then (even though it's a pain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is 
**XAMPP Portable Lite** 
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html.
XAMPP is a "Apache distribution containing MySQL, PHP and Perl" and you can use it for developing your website on your local pc.

Comment: Or WAMP (the pure windows install) http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Cool stuff, I like that it's portable!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is any kind of a so-called "WAMP stack". There are many solutions out there to choose from, see a [comparison of WAMPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs).

Although the most popular one is probably XAMPP, my recommendation would be to use **[Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/)** instead. Uniform Server is much lighter and easier to manage than XAMPP. And it doesn't need an installation, so you can even run it from a USB stick without a problem.